# One or two Israel tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we want separate tags for ancient (biblical) Israel and modern Israel?

It would seem to me that people are fairly likely to be interested in questions about one but not the other.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I don't see the point in having two different Israel tags here.

1. If we did that we would probably need a whole series of tags determining the meaning of Israel in context (Israel the people, Israel the state, Israel of the NT, Israel ancient, Israel modern etc etc etc).
2. Context should dictate pretty clearly which Israel you are talking about.

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: I'll expand. Terseness for effect here :P.

Comment: Tags are largely there for following. Two tags would allow someone to watch for questions about modern Israel while not getting flooded with questions about Ancient Israel.

Comment: And I guess I asked for a one word answer...

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm really trying to think of a case where this is useful and I'm having trouble seeing a question about modern Israel that's on topic.

Comment: Of the seven currently with the tag, two are about Modern Israel.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I see _three_.  ;-)  But I wonder if most of the questions about Modern Israel will be about the extent that it inherits the promises made to the Biblical Israel.  In other words, the questioner has the same group in mind or the question is whether both are the same.  Perhaps having an [tag:ancient] tag and [tag:modern] tag would clear things up?